# How to integrate PHP code into HTML Carousel code?

Tags: php, jquery, html

Can anybody help with the below please. Im having a bit of difficulty getting my head around how to get it to work.

The code is for a thumbnail carousel.

Here is the HTML

```
 <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
 <!-- Carousel items -->
 <div class="carousel-inner">

 <div class="active item" data-slide-number="0">
 <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=one">
 </div>

  <div class="item" data-slide-number="1">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=two">
  </div>

   <div class="item" data-slide-number="2">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=three">
   </div>

   <div class="item" data-slide-number="3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=four">
   </div>

   <div class="item" data-slide-number="4">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=five">
   </div>

   <div class="item" data-slide-number="5">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=six">
   </div>

   </div>
   <!-- Carousel nav -->

 <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>                                       
 </a>

 <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>                                       
 </a>         

 </div>

 <!--thumbnails-->
 <div class="row hidden-xs" id="slider-thumbs">
 <ul class="hide-bullets">
 <li class="col-sm-2">
 <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-0">
 <img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=one">
 </a>
 </li>

 <li class="col-sm-2">
 <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-1">
 <img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=two">
 </a>
 </li>

 <li class="col-sm-2">
 <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-2">
 <img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=three">
 </a>
 </li>

 <li class="col-sm-2">
 <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-3">
 <img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=four">
 </a>
 </li>

 <li class="col-sm-2">
  <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-4">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=five">
  </a>
 </li>

 <li class="col-sm-2">
  <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-5">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=six">
  </a>
 </li>

</ul>                 
</div>
```

The above code works fine, however I am trying to integrate the below PHP code so that the slider has dynamic images with thumbnails.

Here is the PHP code to display the images:

```
        <?php
        if ($images = get_field('images', $design_id)) {
        foreach ($images as $image) {
            echo '<img src="' . $image['image']['sizes']['large'] . '" />';
                                    }
        }
    ?>
```

If anyone could help or point me in the right direction, it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Note where code starts and ends i didn't copy all of your block:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
   <?php
        if ($images = get_field('images', $design_id)) {
        foreach ($images as $key => $image) {
            $active = $key == 0 ? 'active' : '';
            echo '<div class="<?php echo $active;?> item" data-slide-number="<?php echo $key; ?>">';
            echo '<img src="' . $image['image']['sizes']['large'] . '" />';
            echo '</div>';                        }
        }
    ?> 
</div>
```

Explanation. Showing the images is not only to print img src=..., so you have to see what html block to put in the foreach loop so it be showed as the html you posted. $key is the index that you need to mark the slides. $active shows which slide is active, so you need to set it only ones (in our case when $key is 0)

Cheers.

Comment: thank you @bksi that got the slide to work. For the thumbnails would It just be a case of doing the following code:         <?php
        if ($images = get_field('images', $design_id)) {
        foreach ($images as $key => $image) {
            $active = $key == 0 ? 'active' : '';
            echo ' <li class="col-sm-2"><a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-"<?php echo $key; ?>">';
            echo '<img src="' . $image['image']['sizes']['large'] . '" />';
            echo '</li>';                        }
        }
    ?>